# Wordpress + Swup JS / Route plugin + path to regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, routes, swup, path-to-regexp

My URL structure is as follows:

`http://localhost:8888/cdw/work/foo-bar/`
`http://localhost:8888/cdw/work/bar-foo/`
`http://localhost:8888/cdw/work/etc-etc/`

I'm using swup JS and the route plugin https://swup.js.org/plugins/route-name-plugin

None of the following are working. please help. I just need to match any URL that has "work"

Not working

```
new SwupRouteNamePlugin({
    routes: [
        { name: 'work', path: '/work/(.*)'},
    ]
}),
```

Not working:

```
new SwupRouteNamePlugin({
    routes: [
        { name: 'work', path: '/work/*'},
    ]
}),
```

Not working

```
new SwupRouteNamePlugin({
    routes: [
        { name: 'work', path: '/work/:slug'},
    ]
}),
```

Not working:

```
new SwupRouteNamePlugin({
    routes: [
        { name: 'work', path: '/work/'},
    ]
}),
```

What am i missing here? Please help!

Thanks!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the url http://localhost:8888/cdw/work/foo-bar/

I needed to include /cdw/, not just /work/